# Measure A4 size dynamically in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have get data from database and display as a html page.My requirement is that display data in A4 size page with fixed header and footer.

My question is that how to measure A4 paper size dynamically in php ?.

What I have already tried see in below screen shot.

[image]

As per above screen shot part 1 & 3 are fixed height.Only in part 1 & 2 has display data dynamically.Part 2 contains any number of record.

Is it possible if display 1 or 2 item then automatically increase height of part 2 to fit in A4 size.If item is more than 1 page then it is automatically set in another page with fixed header and footer.

**Note: I have used different css for print and display**

Comment: Have a look at [CSS3 Module: Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/).

Comment: @Gumbo Is there any example of A4 paper size using CSS3 module paged media

Answer (score 0):

I would think about it this way:

You could not get height of html element into php directly (at least you could not do it easily without rendering stuff and so on, that's going be a pretty much hassle around), so the only way is make guess about height of future element. What determent of the height? It is content and styles applied to it. In PHP you could get first, eg you can get length of the description, due on, quantity and so on string. Based on this and knowing actual style information you may make pretty good prediction of the row height.

Like this:

Every line suppose to have some fixed height, so just count how many lines fit into the A4 format and than count lines into your PHP script accordingly. If there is multi heights, they should have linear dependency, so it should not be big hassle to find out it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but each row of part 2 comes from database and its data is not fixed may be it is 1 line or more or contains breaks.

Comment: okay, than just get through all variants and find out some distinctive way line was determined, let's say, you have one line without breaks with 20px height, second line with one break which takes 30px and third let's say 45px. than looking up length of, I would assume, description of goods you will be able to say which type of line it would be and than accordingly count future height

Comment: Do you know about How to measure height of td using php ?